# TI Calculator issue in computing sample distribution

Tags: statistics

I've noticed my TI-calculator has been given me these strange answers. I'm sure I did the problem right:

"Biologists are studying a starfish population. The mean starfish length is 18 cm with a standard deviation of 7 cm. If a sample of 49 starfishes are randomly selected, what is the probability that the sample's mean is between 15 to 20 cm?"

I got normalcdf(15,20,18,1) = 0.97589, but when I did normalcdf(-3,3) I got 0.9973. Can someone help me figure out what happened? I standardized it and got a different area which shouldn't happen.

Steps:

$P(15 < X < 20) = normalcdf (15,20,18,1)$
$P\left(\frac{(15-18)}{1} < Z < \frac{20-18}{1}\right) = P(-3 < Z < 3) = normalcdf(-3,3)$

Comment: Can you explain why you think they should be the same? What is the series of steps that you took?

Comment: $\frac{20-18}{1}$ is not equal to $3$.

Comment: Thanks sorry silly mistake